# android (Service & PhoneStateListener) - service does restart but not working when app is killed by task manager, killer or shortage of memory

Tags: android, service, task, restart

This is onStartCommand()

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Notification creation code

    telMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telMgr.listen(new PSL(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

and PhoneStateListener class (under service class)

```
public class PSL extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNum) {
        switch(state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Work1
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //Work2
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

both of them are in same .java file

I have these code on one service class.

when I call `startService()` from main activity, it works well.
but when my app is killed by Task Manager, Killer or automatically by shortage of memory on device, Service does restarts but not working.
when i go to Setting - Application - Running, it shows process 1 and service 1, before/after killed.but after killed, memory share goes 1/10. I have tried startForeground() not to be killed easily with my notification - it didn't work. (doesn't show any notification)
and also tried return of `onStartCommand()`: `START_STICKY`, `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` - shows same result is there any way I can restart completely or make it not killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by startForeground()

It didn't work because I had not used `Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` on Notification

Answer (score 1):

After Spending few Hours I fount that , For Android 2.0 or later you can use the startForeground() method to start your Service in the foreground.
[Documentation provided by Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)

A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)
**Ther are very rare chances of Foreground Service to kill by OS.But It works fine.**

```
public class ServicePhoneState extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Music Player")
           .setTicker("Google Music Player")
           .setContentText("My Music")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bg_icon)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .build();
    startForeground(10, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopForeground(true);
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After Spending few Hours I fount that , For Android 2.0 or later you can use the startForeground() method to start your Service in the foreground.
[Documentation provided by Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service?hl=de#ProcessLifecycle)

A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.) Ther are very rare chances of Foreground Service to kill by OS.But It works fine.

```
public class ServicePhoneState extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new 
MyPhoneStateListener(ServicePhoneState.this);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Music Player")
       .setTicker("Google Music Player")
       .setContentText("My Music")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bg_icon)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .build();
startForeground(10, notification);
return START_NOT_STICKY;}
  @Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
stopForeground(true);
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;}}
```